# vBulletin - extract usernames from user table

Tags: php, sql, vbulletin

I need to extract a list of all usernames from the user table in vBulletin of persons who were registered up to a certain date. So for example, I need all members up until 1st Oct, but after that is not required.

The 'joindate' field is expressed in seconds I think. Eg. 1116022743. How can I can extract usernames on this basis?

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give you an exact answer without knowing the VB table structure, but the query would be something like

```
$date = strtotime('10/01/2010'); 
/* this is the date you are basing our query on
we make a timestamp of it for comparison */

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `vb_users_table` WHERE `joindate` <= '$date'";
```

those "seconds" are timestamps btw (technically seconds, but the correct term is timestamp).

example:

```
<?php

$date = strtotime('10/01/2010'); //1st oct 2010
$old = strtotime('3/9/2009'); // 9th mar 2009
$new = strtotime('3/9/2011') // 9th mar 2011

/* substitute $old with $new to see the effect */
if($old<=$date) { 
    echo date('d M Y', $old) . ' is before ' . date('d M Y', $date);
} else {
    echo date('d M Y', $old) . ' is not before ' . date('d M Y', $date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` MySQL function to help construct the query. Here's a query that will extract the usernames of all the users in a vBulletin installation where their join date is before the 1st of October 2010:

```
SELECT username FROM user WHERE joindate < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2010-10-01 00:00:00');
```

If you want to do the reverse (convert the timestamps from UNIX form into readable ones) you can use `FROM_UNIXTIME`.

Comment: In my case, it was: SELECT username FROM vb_user WHERE joindate < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-10-01 00:00:00');